# [PHP MySQL] Не создается таблица

Tags: mysql, php, sql

```
Помогите люди добрые

**Запрос:**
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
`group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`group_name` text NOT NULL,
`group_info` text NOT NULL,
`owner_login` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `group_id` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Когда я отправляю запрос через phpmyadmin то таблица создается, а если пытаюсь отправить запрос через mysql_query() то таблица не создается. В чем ошибка?
```

Comment: Код-то на PHP покажи, там фиг знает что у тебя творится. Может ты прямо так запрос пишешь, без кавычек. Мы же не знаем...

Хотя чувство, что не читал вот [это](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). А именно "**The query string should not end with a semicolon**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я думаю надо так:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE ИмяТаблицы(ИмяПоля тип,ИмяПоля тип)") or die(mysql_error());
```

и более подробный вариант:

```
db_connect($serverMySql,$db_log,$db_pass);
mysql_select_db($database);
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE users(id int auto_increment primary key,
email TINYTEXT,
password VARCHAR(16),
name TINYTEXT,
daybirth VARCHAR(2),
monthbirth VARCHAR(40),
yearbirth VARCHAR (4))") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
print "Таблица создана!<br>";
```

Ну а если не выходит, то:
[Сюда!](http://www.sdws.ru/topic.php?t=4&id=24)

Comment: Извините что не отформатировал код.

Comment: отформатировал, там же выделаешь код и нажимаешь на фигурные скобки :)

Comment: А как в таком случае указывать тип таблицы и FK, например?

Ну MyIASM может по умолчанию и создается, а если innoDB или NDB?

Comment: Извините, я не супер в запросам SQl  я больше по php и простеньким запросам)).